# Attachment support is disabled when using axistools-maven-plugin

Tags: java, soap, maven, wsdl, axis

I have used the maven plugin `axistools-maven-plugin` in version 1.4 for many projects to build webservice clients from wsdl. And I always get the error message that is coming from wsdl2java:

```
15.07.2011 08:47:02 org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported 
  WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and
  javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
```

Unless the classes are generated correctly, I just wanted to ask if anyone has the same problem and maybe solved it.

*Background of this question is that I will have to implement a webservice interface that is handling the transfer of big files via SOAP WS. So maybe using attachments would be a better choise than dumping the content into an `byte[]`*

Thanks for your comments and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pulling in the javax.mail dependency. The error message states that you will not be able to send mail attachments since you are missing the javax.activation dependency.

This wont influence your SOAP webservice.

Comment: Thanks! I added the dependency directly to the `plugin` section and the warning disapeared.