# How handle Wsdl2Java if `xsd:struct` (Key => Value Map) is defined in WSDL?

Tags: java, php, soap, wsdl, axis

An existing Soap WebServices is providing a WSDL file that specifies an `xsd:struct`.
The WebService is written in PHP.

If I try execute Wsdl2Java goal in my Java, Maven, Spring-ws, Axis Environment, it fails saying:

```
[INFO] [axistools:wsdl2java {execution: default}]
[INFO] about to add compile source root
[INFO] Processing wsdl: /home/foobar/workspace/com.foobar/src/main/wsdl/foobar.wsdl
Sep 17, 2012 2:29:42 AM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error generating Java code from WSDL.

Embedded error: Error running Axis
Type {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}struct is referenced but not defined.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

The WSDL looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Soap_Manager" targetNamespace="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2"/>
    </types>
    <portType name="Soap_ManagerPort">
        <operation name="searchFoo">
            <documentation>searchFoo</documentation>
            <input message="tns:searchFooIn"/>
            <output message="tns:searchFooOut"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="Soap_ManagerBinding" type="tns:Soap_ManagerPort">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="searchFoo">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2#searchFoo"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="Soap_ManagerService">
        <port name="Soap_ManagerPort" binding="tns:Soap_ManagerBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2"/>
        </port>
    </service>
    <message name="searchFooIn">
        <part name="param" type="xsd:struct"/>
    </message>
    <message name="searchFooOut">
        <part name="return" type="xsd:struct"/>
    </message>
</definitions>
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit 1:

This [reference](http://old.apisnetworks.com/soap-wsdl.php) says: 
`...It's xsd:struct, which means it should be treated as an array with multiple values. Most languages render xsd:struct types as hashes with a key => value notation....`

But how to do this with Apache Axis?

Edit 2:

This is the current pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <urls>
                        <url>http://foobar.service.de/wsdlv2.wsdl</url>
                    </urls>
                    <packageSpace>com.foobar.wsdl</packageSpace>
                    <testCases>true</testCases>
                    <serverSide>true</serverSide>
                    <subPackageByFileName>true</subPackageByFileName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <dependencies>      
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>

        </plugins>
...
    </build>
...
```

Edit 3:

An valid Soap Request looks like this (I get it from the doc and tested it with soap-ui):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:emn="interface.foobar">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
    <emn:searchFoobar>
    <emn:searchParameter>
        <emn:username>xxxx</emn:username>
        <emn:password>xxxx</emn:password>
        <emn:maxHitCount>1</emn:maxHitCount>
        <emn:sorting>distance</emn:sorting>
        <emn:searchtext>example</emn:searchtext>        
    </emn:searchParameter>
    </emn:searchFoobar>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler
```

You are missing a jar file from classpath. Probably activation.jar. Please look at [here](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/javax.activation.DataHandler)

Comment: Hi, i added  javax.activation:activation:1.1.1 and javax.mail:mail:1.4.5 with maven but i still get the same error. I guess it is because of xsd:struct

Comment: Btw. here someone has the same problem: http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg67081.html

Comment: Hi, i added the dependencies now directly to the <plugin../> part like mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703638/attachment-support-is-disabled-when-using-axistools-maven-plugin and the DataHandler Warning is gone. But the action error still persits.

Comment: I also found this page. I tried the WebService with Soap UI and it was working fine. But now i have to include it in our application but i don't have an idea how to fix this.

Comment: "I suspect that the problem is related to how the soap_service.module is constructing the wsdl, specifically in defining the Array complexTypes at around line 151. I am using nusoap version 0.7.3 (the latest)." Maybe you have to change something on that module to not generate struct, but a java class instead

Comment: The xsd:struct seems to be an key value store: http://old.apisnetworks.com/soap-wsdl.php ... "It's xsd:struct, which means it should be treated as an array with multiple values. Most languages render xsd:struct types as hashes with a key => value notation." ...

Comment: Other has problems with complex types from PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511153/how-to-read-complextype-with-php?rq=1. The key-value mapping in Java there are "HashMap" and they unsynchronized derivates

Comment: Ok, if this is the problem, i need to know how to fix this with maven axis

Comment: I would re-create that wsdl, to be copmpatible with Java.

Comment: Could you edit the answer maybe and show me how to manipulate this wsdl that i can use a hashmap for this? I attached an tested example how the generated request should look like

Comment: Can't edit the question, not enough reputation yet, just for retag, and I have added PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It looks better:)

```
<emn:searchFoobar>
<emn:searchParameter>
    <emn:username>xxxx</emn:username>
    <emn:password>xxxx</emn:password>
    <emn:maxHitCount>1</emn:maxHitCount>
    <emn:sorting>distance</emn:sorting>
    <emn:searchtext>example</emn:searchtext>        
</emn:searchParameter>
</emn:searchFoobar>
```

In php I would create a class : `searchFooInParamWrapper` class.

That would have: `username`, `password`, `maxHitCount`, `sorting`, `searchtext` fileds.
Hopefully the PHP to WSDL engine it would create a class for :

and remove the struct. And the problem it would be solved easier, than fix the third party library/buggs

Comment: I have to change the wsdl on the client side. The Server is not under my control :(

Comment: I am running out of idea, but what if you extend the Java.util.Hashmap to a "struct" class ( with lowercase letters) ? - to try a trick in Java side? probably it can't be auto-generated the artifacts and you have to write by hand ( or fix library bugs/compatibility.

Comment: I can try that. The problemm is that not very familier to soap. But very thanks for your help! I will open another post how to generate this "datastrutre" with wsdl to hashmap

Comment: I opened this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452030/how-handle-wsdl2java-if-xsdstruct-key-value-map-is-defined-in-wsdl

Comment: Ups, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452537/how-to-specify-a-java-util-hashmap-key-value-in-wsdl