# How to specify a java.util.HashMap (key ==> value) in wsdl

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

An existing WebService (written in PHP) specifies an Key, Value Store as `xsd:struct`. Because Axis doesn't know how to interpretate this, I like to download and patch the Wsdl for my personal use.

At the end, the generated Request should look like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:emn="interface.foobar">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
    <emn:searchFoobar>
    <emn:searchParameter>
        <emn:username>xxxx</emn:username>
        <emn:password>xxxx</emn:password>
        <emn:maxHitCount>1</emn:maxHitCount>
        <emn:sorting>distance</emn:sorting>
        <emn:searchtext>example</emn:searchtext>        
    </emn:searchParameter>
    </emn:searchFoobar>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In this example the `searchParameter` is used as an `java.util.HashMap` on my client. Its childern are the Key and Value entries.

It's like this:

```
<emn:hashmapName>
    <key1>value1</key1>
    <key2>value2</key2>
    <key3>value3</key3>
</emn:hashmapName>
```

The full WSDL looks like this (at the end I like to replace the `xsd:struct` by an `java.util.HashMap`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Soap_Manager" targetNamespace="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2"/>
    </types>
    <portType name="Soap_ManagerPort">
        <operation name="searchFoo">
            <documentation>searchFoo</documentation>
            <input message="tns:searchFooIn"/>
            <output message="tns:searchFooOut"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="Soap_ManagerBinding" type="tns:Soap_ManagerPort">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="searchFoo">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2#searchFoo"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="Soap_ManagerService">
        <port name="Soap_ManagerPort" binding="tns:Soap_ManagerBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://foobar.service.de/service/v2"/>
        </port>
    </service>
    <message name="searchFooIn">
        <part name="param" type="xsd:struct"/>
    </message>
    <message name="searchFooOut">
        <part name="return" type="xsd:struct"/>
    </message>
</definitions>
```

Could somebody show me how specify a `java.util.HashMap` for this kind of use?

Comment: In our services we have a list of properties that can be passed in in key/value pairs. This is defined as a List<Property properties>. That allows us to pass in any number of key/value pairs in a list to the web service.

Comment: That sounds good. Can you please show me how the Wsdl for this looks like?

Comment: what is "xsd:struct"?  there is no such type in xml schema that i'm aware of?  sounds like a broken schema/wsdl

Comment: @jtahlborn that's the problem. It comes from php. See: http://old.apisnetworks.com/soap-wsdl.php

Comment: @Logan if the List<Property> generates this request, you can post the answer and I will vote you up.

Comment: I think you need to use the Axis utility, wsdl2java to generate the java code from your wsdl. I've done this once, but would need to reinstall axis on my pc to do it again. I tried the JBoss wsconsume utility, but because of the RPC encoding in the wsdl it will not work. wsdl2java will work and I'll give it a shot if i can get setup here.

Answer (score 0):

Download apache axis from here [Link to download](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi#std-bin)

Once you download it, unzip it or follow the installation instructions. It comes with a utility called wsdl2java that will read in your wsdl file and build the java classes for it.

I saved your wsdl from above to a file named c:\temp\test.wsdl

Then I ran the wsdl2java command against it like this:

```
wsdl2java -uri c:\temp\test.wsdl
```

It generated a source folder with the package names from your wsdl and 2 java classes that can be used to call that service.